# Create set of matrices from concatenating columns of another matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix, lapply

I have two matrices A and B of dimension 5 by 3 and 5 by 2, respectively. I want to produce series of matrices combining each column of matrix B to A. The dimensions of the resulting matrices would be 5 by 4
Let A be

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
2 3 1
4 1 5
```

and B be

```
    1 2 
    2 5 
    3 8 
    6 3 
    2 1
```

Then the resulting matrices are

```
    1 2 3 1
    4 5 6 2
    7 8 9 3
    2 3 1 6
    4 1 5 2
```

and

```
    1 2 3 2
    4 5 6 5
    7 8 9 8 
    2 3 1 3
    4 1 5 1
```

Comment: I just added an example. I want to do this for large matrices

Comment: Large mean, not exceeding dimensions 100.

Comment: dim(A) = 10 by 5 and dim(B) = 10 by 30.

Answer (score 0):

Use our old friend the assignment operator. Assigning 1st column of B to 4th of A:

```
A[, 4] <- B[, 1]

> A
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  3  1
2  4  5  6  2
3  7  8  9  3
4  2  3  1  6
5  4  1  5  2
```

Then `A[, 4] <- B[, 2]`, etc.